# Are there type-safe equivalents to the comparison operators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just tried the following in a node.js console:

```
> 5 <= "5"
true
```

Which means that the `=` part of the `<=` is treated the same way `==` is, not `===`. Which made me immediately try `<==` hoping it would do what you would hope it would. But it doesn't exist.

Then I tried the following:

```
> 5 < "6"
true
```

Then I started to observe even stranger behaviour:

```
> 5 < [6]
true
```

Which brings up a more important question: are there type-safe equivalents to `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`?

Comment: I edited your title. Your previous title was wondering into "Hey, could a language designer tell me why this feature isn't here?" and this is more, "How do I do type-safe comparison in JavaScript?

Comment: Long story short: no there is not (built-in).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, but it can be handled by correct use of existing language features to type check.

Comparison is ideally two state logic.  Either `a<b` or it is not.  The problem is that combining type checking with comparison changes two state logic into three state (true/false/incomparable).  To return one of three outcomes would no longer be a simple Boolean.

A pre-check on types can already be implemented  with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) or [`instanceOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

If comparisons must be type-appropriate, and there is no code written to deal with mismatches, then an error can be thrown to stop execution as in the following example:

```
if (typeof(a) !== typeof(b)) {
    throw `type mismatch in some_function(), types: ${typeof(a)}, ${typeof(b)}`;
}

// now the next operation is "safe"
if (a <= b) {
    do_something();
} else {
    do_the_other_thing();
}
```

Later when there is error handling code, you can replace the throw or keep the throw and use try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing built in to do so.

Consider:

```
// I invented ~ as the non type coercion operator
5 <~ 6
5 <~ '6'
```

Both of these return false, but the return values don't really mean the same thing. In the second case, it likely wouldn't have even compared the values.